# Setar variáveis de ambiente via shell_exec php

Tags: php, windows, cmd

Preciso fazer um script php para alterar/criar o valor de uma variável de ambiente do windows

```
shell_exec("setx VAR_TEST '2' /M");
```

O comando roda porém não altera o valor da variável, eu rodo usando prompt como administrador.

Comment: E como você verifica se houve a alteração ou não?

Comment: @Woss só lendo HKLM\Environment\\***Variavel**

Answer (score 0):

De fato o valor é **alterado**, mas o respectivo acesso do volar **atualizado** se dá numa nova instancia/sessão.

O **`shell_exec("setx VAR_TEST '2' /M")`** vai criar a variável ou alterar o seu valor para caso da variável já existir.

Entenda que o **`Setx`** só da acesso a variável com o seu valor "atualizado" numa nova instancia/sessão, antes disso para que você tenha acesso "atualizado" do valor de uma variável criada/alterada na mesma instancia/sessão, ou mesmo para verificar se a sua ação de criação/alteração se deu corretamente, recomendo ler os valores das chaves do registro onde o comando **`setx`** vai fazer o efetivo registro/criação das entradas e os seus valores:

> **`HKLM\Environment == para todos usuários`**  quando usado:  **`/m`**
>
> **`HKCU\Environment == para o usuário atual`**

---

Daí fica a dica de escrever e ler direto no registro do windows diretamente no **[php](/questions/tagged/php)**, você não precisa invocar o shell/cmd para executar o **`setx`** que vai escrever, para só na próxima instância/sessão você ter acesso atualizado do valor/variável.

Sugiro consultar essas links sobre como ler/escrever/apagar variáveis/valores no Registro do Windows via **PHP**:

- [Access the Windows Registry with PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/access-the-windows-registry-from-php/)
- [WindowsUserEnvironment.php](https://gist.github.com/johnstevenson/e03d91cdf9406e3e47f7)